# Free Alternatives to Expression Encoder that can publish to IIS Smooth Streaming Server

Tags: iis, iis-7, live-streaming, smooth-streaming

I am looking for a free alternative to Expression Encoder 4 that can stream an output to IIS Live Smooth Streaming. Does anyone know of any they can recommend?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no free alternative for Enconder 4 that can output a Smooth Streaming output.

There some paid alternatives, like Wowza and Unified Streaming Platform (USP) among others.

Comment: Thank you. I've decided to go ahead and get encoder pro since like you stated there is no free alternative.

Answer (score 0):

FFMPEG can do this, but for now you are tied to command line mode, until someone from FFSplit or OBS recognizes, that these tools can be easily fixed to support IIS Publishing Points.

Check out the docs (search for the ismv muxer and http output).

Answer (score 0):

Unreal Media server is working for me. It's a bit obtuse to configure and looks like it escaped from Windows 95 but works. The user limit on the free version isn't a concern since there's never more than one user connected--IIS itself.

http://umediaserver.net

Remember to install a DShow codec pack first.